# Calculating and setting length value for each row in a shapefile returns empty column

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas

I have a Linestrings' shapefile to which I added a column named "length". I want to set the length of each row (geometry) in that column. Here's my code :

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import *
from shapely.ops import transform
from functools import partial
import pyproj

def addLengthField(shapefile, output):
shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(shapefile)
shp['length'] = ''
shp.to_file(output)

addLengthField('./Shapefiles/curbs.shp', './Outputs/curbsWithLength.shp')

def setLengthValue(shapefile, output):
shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(shapefile)
for index, row in shp.iterrows():
    geom = shape(row['geometry'])
   # since the result of geom.length is not in Meters, I wanted to make a transformation
    # Geometry transform partial function based on pyproj.transform
    project = partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4152'),
        pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4152'))
    projectedCurbs = transform(project, geom)

    row['length'] = int(projectedCurbs.length)
    print row['length'] # length values are well displayed
    # Save the final output in another shapefile
shp.to_file(output)

setLengthValue('./Outputs/curbsWithLength.shp','.Outputs/finaloutput.shp')
```

When I run the script the printed values are well displayed but when I open the output shapefile in QGIS the length's column is empty!
Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't actually update the data frame column. Try printing the `shp` before the export and you will see that the `length` column is NaN.

There is no need to iterate the rows of data frame. It is more efficient to use the [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method. Here, we apply the `calc_length` function re-projecting lines and getting their length.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
from functools import partial
import pyproj

shapefile = r'C:\GIS\Temp\Roads.shp'
shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(shapefile)

def calc_length(row):        
    project = partial(pyproj.transform,
                      pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:26912'),
                      pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:{}'.format(epsg_code)))

    shapely_geom = shapely.geometry.shape(row['geometry'])
    proj_line = shapely.ops.transform(project, shapely_geom) 
    return round(proj_line.length,2)

epsg_code = 3857
shp['LengWebMerc'] = shp.apply(calc_length,axis=1)

shp['LengSrc'] = shp['geometry'].length

print shp[['geometry','LengWebMerc','LengSrc']].head(5)
shp.to_file(r'C:\GIS\Temp\RoadsWithLengthCalc.shp')
```

Here I have calculated two new columns - one for the source coord system (can compare with the built-in column `Shape_Leng`) and one for WebMercator (3857).

```
                                            geometry  LengWebMerc  LengSrc
0  LINESTRING (298612.5652000001 4145761.7546, 29...      6328.80  5014.87
1  LINESTRING (298467.2676999997 4141110.3543, 29...      3148.88  2501.91
2  LINESTRING (300608.0926000001 4139778.65530000...      2867.44  2274.21
3  LINESTRING (300608.0926000001 4139778.65530000...        74.89    59.49
4  LINESTRING (300653.7907999996 4139740.57300000...         0.91     0.72
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex Tereshenkov for your answer! I didn't know that the apply method applies the function to each row. Thanks again

Comment: Could you please take a look at my other question ? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206066/how-to-select-features-where-column-matches-a-regex-and-save-them-in-a-new-shape

Comment: @Gisel, no problem at all! I know, pandas can be a bit confusing with the syntax and the logic of accessing rows. I posted an answer to your other question.